# Route model binding not getting data

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to implement route model binding.

**I have my route:**

```
Route::get('/edit/{Word}', 'FlagWordsController@edit')->name('flagwords.edit');
```

**I click on a link within a foreach loop:**

```
@foreach ($words as $word)
     <tr>

                    <td>
                        <a class="atrium-button--text" href="{{ route('flagwords.edit', $word->id) }}">
                            <svg width="18" height="18" viewbox="0 0 18 18">
                            <use xlink:href="#icon-edit"></use></svg>
                            <span>Edit</span>
                        </a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            @endforeach
```

**This is my controller:**

```
public function edit(Word $word)
{
    dd($word);
    return view('backend.flag-words.create', compact('word'));
}
```

**But the data when I dd is empty..**

Comment: You should be using `{word}` not `{Word}` since it should match the parameter name, not the class name.

Answer (score 0):

You can try doing an Explicit Binding.To register an explicit binding, use the router's `model` method to specify the class for a given parameter. You should define your explicit model bindings in the boot method of the  `Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php` class:

```
public function boot()
{
 parent::boot();

 Route::model('word', App\Word::class);
}
```

Next, define a route that contains a `{word}` parameter:

```
Route::get('edit/{word}','FlagWordsController@edit');
```

So, for example, a request to `word/1` will inject the `Word` instance from the database which has an ID of 1.